# webpack seems not recognizing the 'module' or 'define' in if condition

Tags: module, webpack

the code below won't work in webpack, can't export the right result.

```
if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
} else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
} else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
}
```

but these code works well:

```
"function"==typeof define && define.amd
?
define(function() {
    return FastClick;
})
:
"undefined"!=typeof module && "undefined"!=typeof module.exports
?
module.exports= FastClick
:
window.FastClick=FastClick
```

does webpack not read the code in if condition?

and i found that the `;` at the begining of the module also causes different result:

```
;(function () {...} ());
```

is different with

```
(function () {...} ());
```

in webpack ^2.2.1

Comment: Webpack has no problems finding references to `exports` or `define` in `if` blocks. The first and second block in your example do different things, however. What is this `factory(require('jquery'))` all about?

Comment: the `factory` means nothing. it's just an example. please try the two different way of exports.